# removing the “T” from a datetime when doing a XML + XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I am pulling in change date which comes in XML as `<Attribute name="ChangeDate">2013-06-03T16:54:11.513</Attribute>`. I need to remove the `T` separator. I am using VBScript code that is calling my XSLT but I don't know how to remove the `T` separator.

Here is a sample of my XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="Assets">
    <Stories>
        <xsl:for-each select="Asset">
            <Asset>
                <ChangeDate>
                    <xsl:value-of select="Attribute[@name='ChangeDate']"/>
                </ChangeDate>
                <CreateDate>
                    <xsl:value-of select="Attribute[@name='CreateDate']"/>
                </CreateDate>
            </Asset>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Stories>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I am surprised that even VBScript won't accept the `T` in an ISO 8601 standard date and time. Do you want it removed completely, giving `2013-06-0316:54:11.513` (which seems very unlikely) or do you want a space there instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look to [`translate()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-translate):

Try:

```
<xsl:value-of select="translate(Attribute[@name='ChangeDate'], 'T', '')"/>
```

Comment: @user2475781 If this was what you are looking for, please consider to mark the answer as valid.